# PHPExcel: Display chart X-Axis labels

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to display X-Axis label on my chart generated via PHPExcel. However it only gives me default names (1, 2, 3 and Series1) instead of the real labels.

Here is the code I use:

```
        $xlsSheet->fromArray($exportAnswers, null, 'A1');

        $dataseriesLabels = array(
            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', '!$A$2:$A$4', NULL, 3)
        );

        $xAxisTickValues = array(
            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', '!$A$2:$A$4', NULL, 3)
        );

        $dataSeriesValues = array(
            new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', '!$B$2:$B$4', NULL, 3)
        );

        $series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
            PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
            NULL,                                           // plotGrouping
            range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1),         // plotOrder
            $dataseriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
            $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
            $dataSeriesValues,                              // plotValues
            NULL
        );
        $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

        $plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
        $legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
        $title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title($b['block_title']);

        $chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
            $b['block_title'],      // name
            $title,                 // title
            $legend,                // legend
            $plotarea,      // plotArea
            true,           // plotVisibleOnly
            0,              // displayBlanksAs
            NULL,           // xAxisLabel
            NULL            // yAxisLabel
        );

        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('H2');
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('P20');
        $xlsSheet->addChart($chart);
```

And here is the result in Excel:

[Result in Excel](http://carsell.remedy-creation.com/uploads/535b25a565249110484b2551/53b4a013a74de.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `!` from `'!$A$2:$A$4'` or include the actual worksheet name before the `!`